# What are the restriction for code inside catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So are there any specific restrictions for writting code inside catch block?

PS. This question was asked by my friend's java programming teacher on the exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this feature, now you can catch multiple exceptions in single catch   block. Before java 7, you was restricted to catch only one. To specify the list of expected exceptions a pipe (‘|’) character is used.

```
Lets understand using an example.

try
{
       //Do some processing which throws NullPointerException; I am sending directly
       throw new NullPointerException();
}

//You can catch multiple exception added after 'pipe' character
catch(NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{
       throw ex;
}
```

Remember: If a catch block handles more than one exception type, then the catch parameter is implicitly final. In this example, the catch parameter ex is final and therefore you cannot assign any values to it within the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html):

```
CatchClause:  
    catch ( {VariableModifier} CatchType Identifier ) Block
```

So, you can write anything you can write in any other block.